# Scrapy web crawler's css & xpath selectors vs BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xpath, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy for a large scale project and a significant part of the computation goes into parsing the web pages.

I was wondering if the `css` and the `xpath` selectors of Scrapy are optimized for the best algorithmic efficiency or should i use `BeautifulSoup4` which happens to use lxml internally.

Comment: Why don't you try to benchmark your code using both library  and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you [read the docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html) you can see:

> Scrapy selectors are built over the lxml library, which means they’re very similar in speed and parsing accuracy.

This means if you use Scrapy to scrape the data the XPath selectors are same in speed with BS4 -- and you get some parallelism out of the box which speeds up your task even more.